# Java exception error javax.xml.transform.TransformerConfigurationException when transforming xml using xslt

Tags: java, xml, xslt

I have used one xslt to find the xpath of element. I run the xslt using java coding. But I got an exception error.
The xslt coding is as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" exclude-result-prefixes="xs" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="no"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
<value>
<xsl:for-each select="//section">
    <xsl:variable name="xpath-name" select="string-join((for $node in ancestor::* return $node/name(),name()),'/')"></xsl:variable>
    <path><xsl:value-of select="$xpath-name"/></path>
</xsl:for-each>
</value>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The java coding I used as below:

```
package firstspring;
import java.io.File;
import javax.xml.transform.*;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.*;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    TransformerFactory tFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
            StreamSource xmlInputFile = new StreamSource("E:/test/test.xml");
            StreamSource xslTransformationFile = new StreamSource("E:/test/my.xsl");
            StreamResult xmlOutputFile = new StreamResult("E:/test/out.xml");
            try {
                Transformer transformer = tFactory
                        .newTransformer(xslTransformationFile);
                transformer.transform(xmlInputFile, xmlOutputFile);
            } catch (TransformerConfigurationException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (TransformerException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println("Done!");
try{

}
catch (Exception e) {
    // TODO: handle exception
}

    }

}
```

Below exception error occured:

```
FATAL ERROR:  'file:///E:/test/my.xsl: line 8: Required attribute 'select' is missing.'
javax.xml.transform.TransformerConfigurationException: file:///E:/test/my.xsl: line 8: Required attribute 'select' is missing.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl.newTemplates(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl.newTransformer(Unknown Source)
    at firstspring.fileread.main(fileread.java:36)
```

Please anyone help:

Comment: Xalan is an XSLT 1 processor while you have fed it an XSLT 2 stylesheet. You will need to switch to Saxon 9 as the XSLT processor to use XSLT 2 or 3, it should suffice to put Saxon 9 HE from saxonica.com or Maven or Sourceforge on the classpath.

Comment: I have saxon 9 jar, but I dont know where to add or replace it.

Comment: whether I need to change any coding?

Comment: I can't answer that question "where to add" the jar, that depends on how you write and deploy your Java code (i.e. the IDE and the packaging you use, you will need to edit your question with details and tags about that if you want to find people being able to help).

Comment: In general, if you know you have Saxon 9 HE, then I think Saxonica/Michael Kay recommend to avoid the JAXP factory finding mechanism with `TransformerFactory.newInstance()` and to simply use `TransformerFactory tFactory = new net.sf.saxon.TransformerFactoryImpl()`, see also http://saxonica.com/html/documentation/using-xsl/embedding/jaxp-transformation.html for details on that and http://saxonica.com/html/documentation/about/installationjava/ for installation advice.

Comment: Thanks. But I cant able to pick this.

Comment: @Reegan, I don't understand "I cant able to pick this". What are you doing and how does it fail?

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned in the comments by @Martin Honnen, you need to add either `saxon9he.jar` or some other version of the jar to support XSLT 2.0.

Looking at your Java code, it looks like you are just trying to check the transformation since the logic is written in a `main` method. In case this class is part of a Java project, you can add the jar file dependency to the `classpath` of the project.

If the class is part of a deployable viz. `.war` file, then add the jar in the `/WEB-INF/lib` folder and the dependency will be handled.